# Becoming a CFI in the USA as a non-US citizen

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi

This question is not about aviation itself, but rather about job opportunities in aviation.

It kind of goes into law a little, maybe somebody has some experience with this issue though:

Being from Germany, I'd like to become a FAA CFI. This itself is not a huge problem, but working as a CFI in the US is one, as I would need a citizenship or a green card to work there... or would I not?

Does anybody know anyone who is a CFI or works as a pilot in the US and is not a US-citizen?
Or does anybody have an idea of how to work as a CFI without a green card or citizenship?

Knowing this isn't pure aviation, this still appears to me as one of the best places to ask, you all know that experience can not be out ruled!

Comment: This is really a question about employment law, not about aviation. To legally work in the US as a foreigner you need a green card or an appropriate visa (not all visas allow you to work!), but there are lots of rules about how to get them and it all depends on your personal situation. I suggest you try [expatriates.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), they seem to have a lot of questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to be a citizen to be a U.S. CFI.

You need to have US ratings, so you would have to have all your German licenses/ratings converted, which takes some time.

You have to be absolutely FLUENT in both spoken and written English.

If you want to charge students money for your services, you have to have US residency or other work visa authorization. You do not need a work visa if you train students for free.

Comment: I know this question is closed, but I wanted to point out that the question wasn't about 'can a foreigner become an FAA CFI?' (he specifically says he knows that's possible) — it's 'can a foreigner work as a CFI in the US?'.

Comment: @egid Well, that would be a legal question that has nothing to do with aviation. As I pointed out in my answer, you have to have a work authorization to do ANY job in the US.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That's why it got closed. :)